# Converting string to currency and globalization issue

Tags: c#, string, globalization

I have this:

```
var pl = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");
decimal valsue = decimal.Parse("2,25 PLN", pl);
```

It works ok if i don't put "PLN" into my string. But PLN is currency in my country and i think that it should parse, so maybe i am doing something wrong? Is there any option to parse this into decimal with "PLN" attached to the string?

Comment: If it works without it, why do you need to have it as part of the string?

Comment: Just being curious, also it would save me unnecesary `string.replace("PLN","")`.

Comment: This works: `decimal.Parse("2,25 zł", NumberStyles.Currency, pl)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at your `CultureInfo`'s [`NumberFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xdwt6xx.aspx) object, this will yield some clues about how it intends to parse values. In particular, `NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` for the "pl-PL" culture is `zł`.

In other words, this expression would parse successfully: `decimal.Parse("2,25 zł", pl);`

If you prefer to use PLN as the currency symbol (technically, it's the currency *code*), it is possible to configure a custom `NumberFormat`, like so:

```cs
var pln = (NumberFormatInfo) pl.NumberFormat.Clone(); // Clone is needed to create a copy whose properties can be set.
pln.CurrencySymbol = "PLN";
decimal valsue = decimal.Parse("2,25 PLN", NumberStyles.Currency, pln);
```

But note the usage of [`NumberStyles.Currency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) in the Parse call: by default, `decimal.Parse` accepts only strings containing numeric values, without currency formatting.

Comment: Note that in the original `pl` culture, the symbol is `"zł"` with a lower-case L with stroke, not just `"zl"`. I found out because I couldn't get parsing with `"zl"` to work. It's confusing because in some lame Microsoft fonts, like the one I have in my Console application windows and PowerShell windows, you can't tell the difference between `l` and `ł`. Microsoft should use a better font in their consoles.

Comment: I had *exactly* the same problem, and have updated the symbol in my answer to contain the [correct Unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/142/index.htm). Exasperating!